# Search text after specific string

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to search for specific text after a certain string. 
The catch is that this specific string exists twice in my text.
It's like this:

> *Billing information* 
>   Name:  SomeName
>   Address: SomeAddress 
>   City: SomeCity
>   
>   *Shipping Information*
>   Name: SomeName
>   Address: SomeAddress
>   City: SomeCity

So far I'm using this regular expression:

```
(?<=Name:).*
```

This gets me both Names.
How would I get just the Name from under Shipping Information?

Edit:
I can use multiple matches of course, and loop through them, but I would prefer to have a single statement for each. So one statement for Shipping Name, and one statement for Billing name.

Comment: Use that regex first for the billing information and then for the shipping information.

Comment: if you are doing multiline regex, can you include 'Shipping Information' before the name? or just specify that 100 characters of something needs to appear before 'name'?

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET multiline

Comment: I tried variations of (?<=.*Shipping.*Name:).* but that does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^Name: (.+)$` with the global and multiline flags.

Comment: I have the multiline flag, but what is the 'global' flag? I can't seem to find that in the Regex options

Comment: The regex engine will usually stop after the first match; with the global flag (`g`), it will do an iterative match and find all instances of the pattern. With the regex I've given above, I've used a capturing group around what would be your name data; if your regex engine has a matching function that populates an array with each match it finds, you'll get a result like ['SomeBillingName', 'SomeShippingName']

Comment: Ah, yes, I've found that. But is it also possible to construct an expression that only finds the second one?

Comment: Yes...but it's easier to find both and just pick out the second one!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
  ^Name: (\w*)
```

or

```
 (?<=Name:)(.*)
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just enumerating thru the matches?

[Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8.aspx)